# Bound Value gets reset to the empty string

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

For my WPF application, I created several `UserControls` which each have their own **ViewModel**. The *ViewModels* are all based on a `PageViewModelBase` which contains a variable "**_context**".

The `UserControls` are presented as pages in a Wizard Dialog, which has its own **WizardViewModel**. *WizardViewModel* has the variable `_masterContext` which is passed to the respective child ViewModels via their constructors. For example,

```
Child1ViewModel vm = new Child1ViewModel(_masterContext);
```

and the constructor of Child1ViewModel :

```
public Child1ViewModel(Context context) : base(context)
```

and the PageViewModelBase :

```
protected PageViewModelBase(Context context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

My intention is to have **only 1 _masterContext**, which can be accessed via each of the ChildViewModels. And each of the child views can bind to this and supply values to various fields in the master context.

However I am encountering the problem that a field that I bind to `TextBox.Text` gets reset to "" whenever I switch from childView1 to childView2. I'm not sure is this due to my MMI code, or there are more than 1 instance of _masterContext in the application, i.e. my method above is not doing as it should.

**What could be causing this?**

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the culprit resetting the value. I implemented a behavior to handle the TextChanged event of the TextBox. Somehow that used in conjunction with the Binding will cause the value to be reset. Once I took that away, the binding was working fine.

Due to my limited knowledgem I'm unable to explain why. But thanks all for your time.